# Is it guaranteed that non-numeric attribute values on every web-page HTML are always quoted?

Tags: html

I'm parsing the source code of different web pages.

I'm not sure whether or not it is guaranteed that it will always be in HTML format, but for the sake of this question, it is all I'm interested in (i.e., you can assume that my question refers to HTML pages).

Now, I read the standard for XML and XHTML, stating that the value of every attribute, whether it's numeric or not, has to be quoted (encapsulated with `"`).

But I have not been able to find this issue on the HTML standard.

If I remember correctly, numeric values are not necessarily quoted.

What about non-numeric values? Can I assume that they are always quoted?

Thanks

Comment: No. It is not guaranteed. Who would guarantee it?

Comment: There are very few things you can assume when parsing arbitrary HTML. You definitely *cannot* assume that unknown web pages will use standards compliant HTML. There are very few that do! The W3C standards won't be much help, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML standard doesn't require attributes to be quoted, see [HTML5 - The HTML syntax - Attributes](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#elements-attributes)

> *8.1.2.3 Attributes*
>   ...
>   Attributes can be specified in four different ways:
>   Empty attribute syntax
>   Unquoted attribute value syntax
>   Single-quoted attribute value syntax
>   Double-quoted attribute value syntax

Comment: Thanks; and if quoted, can it be also with single quotes, or only with double quotes?

Comment: See the link to the HTML5 standard. I also quoted the relevant parts.